# how to formulate the proper mongo query to get the records in proper format

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

Here I want to make a query which binds the data according to the `parent`. I'm receiving the objects below:

```
{
  "_id" : 1,
  "name" : "home",
  "slug" : "home",
  "parent" : 0,
  "description" : "this will direct you on home page",
  "order" : 1,
  "taxonomy" : "nav_bar"
}
{
  "_id" : 2,
  "name" : "Links",
  "slug" : "links",
  "parent" : 0,
  "description" : "this will direct you on home page",
  "order" : 2,
  "taxonomy" : "nav_bar"
}
{
  "_id" : 3,
  "name" : "Link1",
  "slug" : "link1",
  "parent" : 2,
  "description" : "this will direct you on home page",
  "order" : 1,
  "taxonomy" : "nav_bar"
}
{
  "_id" : 4,
  "name" : "Link2",
  "slug" : "link2",
  "parent" : 2,
  "description" : "this will direct you on home page",
  "order" : 2,
  "taxonomy" : "nav-bar"
}
{
  "_id" : 5,
  "name" : "extra Link",
  "slug" : "extra-link",
  "parent" : 0,
  "description" : "this will direct you on home page",
  "order" : 3,
  "taxonomy" : "nav-bar"
}
{
  "_id" : 6,
  "name" : "extra Link1",
  "slug" : "extra-link1",
  "parent" : 5,
  "description" : "this will direct you on home page",
  "order" : 1,
  "taxonomy" : "nav-bar"
}
{
  "_id" : 7,
  "name" : "extra Link2",
  "slug" : "extra-link2",
  "parent" : 5,
  "description" : "this will direct you on home page",
  "order" : 2,
  "taxonomy" : "nav-bar"
}
```

How will I retrieve this data using golang according to the `parent` field and the `order` field that they are in sorted order and also follow the child parent hierarchy. For now I'm simply retrieving all the data by using `db.CollectionName.find().pretty()`. But now I have to order this by order field and also with parent child hierarchy.

I have tried below query in mongodb shell:-

```
db.CollectionName.find().pretty()
```

it will show me the full data. But I need for example record first having `_id:1, parent:0, order:1` then it will show at the top and record second having `_id:2, parent:0, order:2` it will show on second, in third record it will having `_id:3, parent:2, order:1` then it will show just behind the record second because its parent is `_id:2` on order first.

Comment: What have you tried? Include your code. What problem are you facing?

Comment: @Flimzy sir I perform the above written query in mongo shell and it will give me full records but I want to get the records on the bases of order and parent. for example record first having `_id:1, parent:0, order:1` then it will show at the top and record second having `_id:2, parent:0, order:2` it will show on second, in third record it will having `_id:3, parent:2, order:1` then it will show just behind the record second because its parent is `_id:2` on order first. like that. Understand?

Comment: Is your question how to bind data, then, or how to formulate the proper mongo query? These are unrelated questions. In either case, please update your question with your query and/or relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your question.

I think you're trying to do the following.

- get some data from mongo (you seem to have that covered)
- get it into go for further processing
- sort it by parent and order

When you say "binding data" you might mean unmarshal to a data structure.  For that you'll need a struct to support your data.  Here's a suggestion auto generated from [JSON-to-Go](https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/):

```
type Obj struct {
ID          int    `json:"_id"`
Name        string `json:"name"`
Slug        string `json:"slug"`
Parent      int    `json:"parent"`
Description string `json:"description"`
Order       int    `json:"order"`
Taxonomy    string `json:"taxonomy"`
}
```

You might want to rename the struct something better than 'Obj'.

To unmarshal get the JSON and set it to a string, `s` for example.

create an array to contain your objects

```
var obj []Obj
```

and do something like:

```
err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &obj)
```

after that you can sort it how you like.

Here's a link to the Go docs for sorting.
https://golang.org/pkg/sort/